# nginx 3rd party healthcheck module: still useful, works w 1.6 and 1.7?

Tags: nginx

The 3rd party module for healthchecks:
https://github.com/cep21/healthcheck_nginx_upstreams

has not been updated for 5 years.

Is it still the right tool to use for health checks?
Works w 1.6 and 1.7 of nginx?

Comment: https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_upstream_check_module

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks! By default, centos installs nginx 1.6.... which is not on the ver list.  1.5 patch level should fly?

Comment: That's the repo that comes up when I searched for "nginx upstream health check". It is of course a fork of the one you mentioned. I'd ask its author what to do for 1.6. Also, you should know that the commercial version of nginx has built in health checks.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, we know the commercial ver has health checks. We may have to use it, but we need a few instances, and the cost adds up fast.

Comment: I'd strongly consider switching to HAProxy, then. :)

Comment: We like haproxy, but our hosting service supports nginx, but not haproxy.

Comment: @samsmith If you like adventure you can try [tengine](https://github.com/alibaba/tengine), a chinese fork of nginx from alibaba (largest e-commerce company in china). It includes [healthchecks](http://tengine.taobao.org/document/http_upstream_check.html) by default.